# Looping jQuery Switch case

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, while-loop

I'm currently using the code below.

It work just fine, however the jQuery script seems like a massive waste of code for me. However, I'm not sure how to correctly use a `while` loop to fit this situation.
What's the best way to do it efficiently?

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid1">
    <h5>Div Quantity <input id="divs_qt" type="number" min="1" max="20" step="1" value="1"></h5>
    <div id="div01">
        <h6>Div 01</h6>
        <p class="div">
            <label for="div01_info01">Info 01</label>
            <input type="text" name="div01_info01" id="div01_info01">
        </p>
        <p class="div">
            <label for="div01_info02">Info 02</label>
            <input type="text" name="div01_info02" id="div01_info02">
        </p>
        <p class="div">
            <label for="div01_info03">Info 03</label>
            <input type="text" name="div01_info03" id="div01_info03">
        </p>
        <p class="div">
            <label for="div01_info04">Info 04</label>
            <input type="text" name="div01_info04" id="div01_info04">
        </p>
        <p class="div">
            <label for="div01_info05">Info 05</label>
            <input type="text" name="div01_info05" id="div01_info05">
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="div02">
        <h6>Div 02</h6>
        <p class="div">
            <label for="div02_info01">Info 01</label>
            <input type="text" name="div02_info01" id="div02_info01">
        </p>
        <p class="div">
            <label for="div02_info02">Info 02</label>
            <input type="text" name="div02_info02" id="div02_info02">
        </p>
        <p class="div">
            <label for="div02_info03">Info 03</label>
            <input type="text" name="div02_info03" id="div02_info03">
        </p>
        <p class="div">
            <label for="div02_info04">Info 04</label>
            <input type="text" name="div02_info04" id="div02_info04">
        </p>
        <p class="div">
            <label for="div02_info05">Info 05</label>
            <input type="text" name="div02_info05" id="div02_info05">
        </p>
    </div>
    <!-- Etc... -->
    <div id="div20">
        <h6>Div 20</h6>
        <p class="div">
            <label for="div20_info01">Info 01</label>
            <input type="text" name="div20_info01" id="div20_info01">
        </p>
        <p class="div">
            <label for="div20_info02">Info 02</label>
            <input type="text" name="div20_info02" id="div20_info02">
        </p>
        <p class="div">
            <label for="div20_info03">Info 03</label>
            <input type="text" name="div20_info03" id="div20_info03">
        </p>
        <p class="div">
            <label for="div20_info04">Info 04</label>
            <input type="text" name="div20_info04" id="div20_info04">
        </p>
        <p class="div">
            <label for="div20_info05">Info 05</label>
            <input type="text" name="div20_info05" id="div20_info05">
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#divs_qt").change(function() {
    switch (this.value) {
        case "1":
            $("#div01").css({display: "block"});
            $("#div02").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div03").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div04").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div05").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div06").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div07").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div08").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div09").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div10").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div11").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div12").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div13").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div14").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div15").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div16").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div17").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div18").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div19").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div20").css({display: "none"});
            break;
        case "2":
            $("#div01").css({display: "block"});
            $("#div02").css({display: "block"});
            $("#div03").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div04").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div05").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div06").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div07").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div08").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div09").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div10").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div11").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div12").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div13").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div14").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div15").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div16").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div17").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div18").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div19").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div20").css({display: "none"});
            break;
        // etc...
        case "20":
            $("#div01").css({display: "block"});
            $("#div02").css({display: "block"});
            $("#div03").css({display: "block"});
            $("#div04").css({display: "block"});
            $("#div05").css({display: "block"});
            $("#div06").css({display: "block"});
            $("#div07").css({display: "block"});
            $("#div08").css({display: "block"});
            $("#div09").css({display: "block"});
            $("#div10").css({display: "block"});
            $("#div11").css({display: "block"});
            $("#div12").css({display: "block"});
            $("#div13").css({display: "block"});
            $("#div14").css({display: "block"});
            $("#div15").css({display: "block"});
            $("#div16").css({display: "block"});
            $("#div17").css({display: "block"});
            $("#div18").css({display: "block"});
            $("#div19").css({display: "block"});
            $("#div20").css({display: "block"});
            break;
        default:
            $("#div01").css({display: "block"});
            $("#div02").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div03").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div04").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div05").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div06").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div07").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div08").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div09").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div10").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div11").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div12").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div13").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div14").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div15").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div16").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div17").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div18").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div19").css({display: "none"});
            $("#div20").css({display: "none"});
    }
});
```

Complete working code at: http://jsfiddle.net/9g5y3fa3/

Comment: First, what are you trying to do? Second, oh god my eyes.

Comment: Code reviews belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I agree with @j08691, but please do not create a duplicate question on codereview. Flag a mod and ask them to move it for you.

Comment: @Henrique Foletto Your code hangs the browser.. :)

Comment: @DesertIvy I heard in some countries developers get salary based on lines of code written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is flawed. One very important principle in application development is "[Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)", or [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) for short.

Rather than repeating 20 items over and over again, use a single template and then render that template as many times as you need. [Girish has already given you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25625700/211627) an example using a custom-made templating system, but I recommend using something a tad more powerful like [HandlebarsJS](http://handlebarsjs.com/). It gives you a lot more room to grow when you realize that you need more nuance in your template.

You don't even need to download or install anything - just use the [Handlebars CDN](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/handlebars.js/) (include handlebars.js and handlebars.runtime.js via a `<script src=""></script>` tag).

Your code will end up looking something like this:

#### HTML

A single HTML template. Very handy if you realize you need info06 added to the form.

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0-alpha.4/handlebars.runtime.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0-alpha.4/handlebars.js"></script>
<script id="item-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div id="div{{index}}">
        <h6>Div {{index}}</h6>
        <p class="div">
            <label for="div{{index}}_info01">Info 01</label>
            <input type="text" name="div{{index}}_info01" id="div{{index}}_info01" />
        </p>
        <p class="div">
            <label for="div{{index}}_info02">Info 02</label>
            <input type="text" name="div{{index}}_info02" id="div{{index}}_info02" />
        </p>
        <p class="div">
            <label for="div{{index}}_info03">Info 03</label>
            <input type="text" name="div{{index}}_info03" id="div{{index}}_info03" />
        </p>
        <p class="div">
            <label for="div{{index}}_info04">Info 04</label>
            <input type="text" name="div{{index}}_info04" id="div{{index}}_info04" />
        </p>
        <p class="div">
            <label for="div{{index}}_info05">Info 05</label>
            <input type="text" name="div{{index}}_info05" id="div{{index}}_info05" />
        </p>
    </div>
</script>
<div class="grid1">
    <h5>Div Quantity <input id="divs_qt" type="number" min="1" max="20" step="1" value="1" /></h5>
    <div id="container">
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Javascript

```
var container = $("#container");
var source    = $("#item-template").html();
var template  = Handlebars.compile(source);

// Pre-render the items
var prerenderedItems = [];
for ( var i = 1; i <= 20; i++ ){
    var context = { index: ( i < 10 ? '0' + i : '' + i ) }
    prerenderedItems.push( $( template(context) ) );
}

// Render 1 item for the initial load
renderItems(1);

function renderItems( itemCount ){
    // Detach all prerendered items from the DOM
    $.each( prerenderedItems, function(){ this.detach(); } );

    for ( var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++ ){
        // Reattach the appropriate items
        container.append( prerenderedItems[i] );
    }
}

$("#divs_qt").change(function() {
    renderItems( this.value );
});
```

That's it!

See a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/5q1k5v8d/7/

Comment: Thank you a lot, my dear. My question was dumb, but I always had problems to fully understand JS loops, but here you explained it really well to me. I'm so glad I haven't hesitated asking.

Comment: Hey, when you change the value of the input[type=number], the values of every input in the loop resets. Is there a way to preserve the values? It would make it perfect. And hey, I already used the knowledge you shared with me in another code, thank you so much for teaching me.

Comment: Thank you so much again. I'll never repeat myself again!

Answer (score 1):

That can be reduced to :

```
$("#divs_qt").change(function() {
    var $div = $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    $div.slice(0, this.value).show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9g5y3fa3/4/

Or all chained together:

```
$("#divs_qt").change(function() {
    $('div[id^=div]').hide().slice(0, this.value).show();
});
```

Comment: That's nice, much cleaner than using `.filter()`.

Comment: @Illusion I don't exactly see how replacing `this.value` with a `parseInt(...)` of it is reducing. Not to mention that the default radix in the above cases would be 10 anyway.

Comment: @Nit the parse was in my original answer, he just copied it. His point was the chaining! Anyway, spot on!

Answer (score 0):

Try simple code

```
$("#divs_qt").change(function () {
    $("div[id*=div]").css({
        display: "none"
    });
    for (var i = 1; i <= parseInt(this.value); i++) {
        $(i < 10 ? "div[id=div0" + i + "]" : "div[id=div" + i + "]")
            .css({
            display: "block"
        });
    }
});
```

**Updated code** as comment best by use template and append `element` as per counter

**Script**

```
$("#yd").html($("#template").html().replace(/\@/g, "01"));
$("#divs_qt").change(function() {
    $("#yd").empty();
    for(var i = 1; i <= parseInt(this.value); i++){
         $("#yd").append($("#template").html().replace(/\@/g, i))         
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/templeate" id="template">

                <div id="div@">
            <h6>Div @</h6>
            <p class="div">
                <label for="div@_info01">Info 01</label>
                <input type="text" name="div@_info01" id="div@_info01">
            </p>
            <p class="div">
                <label for="div@_info02">Info 02</label>
                <input type="text" name="div@_info02" id="div@_info02">
            </p>
            <p class="div">
                <label for="div@_info03">Info 03</label>
                <input type="text" name="div@_info03" id="div@_info03">
            </p>
            <p class="div">
                <label for="div@_info04">Info 04</label>
                <input type="text" name="div@_info04" id="div@_info04">
            </p>
            <p class="div">
                <label for="div@_info05">Info 05</label>
                <input type="text" name="div@_info05" id="div@_info05">
            </p>
        </div>
            </script>
<div class="grid1">
    <h5>Div Quantity <input id="divs_qt" type="number" min="1" max="20" step="1" value="1"></h5>
        <div id="yd"></div>
</div>
```

[**FIDDLE Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9g5y3fa3/2/)

Comment: Yeah... works until you get to div10. A proper solution would be to use a proper framework like [Angular](https://angularjs.org/), or even just some sort of templating approach like [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

Comment: There are still major scalability issues. A proper solution would use templating.

Comment: @JDB no need  to use complex template framework here, this works fine also, see updated code

Comment: Handlebars is not complicated... it's at least as easy as your de-facto templating system and much, much more powerful. http://jsfiddle.net/5q1k5v8d/2/

Comment: @jdb I didn't ever use Handlebars, way of working almost similar thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Anoop's answer, but this uses the "each" method to create a loop across each of the divs, showing or hiding them based on whether their index is as high as the chosen value.

```
$("#divs_qt").change(function() {
    var value = this.value;
    $("div[id^=div]").each(function(i) {
        $(this).toggle(i < value);
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7wL6w4h3/)

Answer (score -1):

I have edited Girish's answer a little and this is working even after 10

```
$("#divs_qt").change(function() {
    $("div[id*=div]").css({display: "none"});
    for(var i = 1; i <= parseInt(this.value); i++){
        if(i <= 9){
            $("div[id=div0" + i + "]").css({display: "block"});
        }else{
            $("div[id=div" + i + "]").css({display: "block"});
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I dont know why, they probably didn't like the solution :/ Just FYI, it would be better to use `#` selector : `$("#div0" + i + "]")` for example.